# Control Webcam settings programmatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows, webcam

I'm looking to control the settings of my webcam (mainly focus) while the device is in use by another application (OBS).

Is it possible?

I've tried [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls) for UWP, while I was able to control the focus of my camera with some modifications, it only allows that control if it gets full access to the camera, which it doesn't have if I open OBS up first.

My camera is a Logitech C920 using the generic windows drivers (not the Logitech ones)

Currently I can change the values using the webcams properties windows, but I would eventually like to make a physical controller to change it (But I'm not worried about that part right now!)

[image: Webcam Settings]

Answer (score 0):

This script over here launches the Camera / Webcam Properties window directly - maybe something here can help?

https://superuser.com/a/1544770
(direct link to repo: https://github.com/jpalbert/webcam-settings-dialog-windows )